# IPA dynamic DNS updates only the AAAA record. Where are my A records?

Tags: centos6, dynamic-dns, sssd, freeipa

I'm setting up a FreeIPA domain. In my lab are three virtual machines: the domain controller `ipadc1`, and two clients `puppet` and `wordpress` (creative, yes, I know). All three VMs are running freshly installed CentOS 6.4 (FreeIPA 3.0.0).

I've installed the IPA server, creating a domain which we'll call `example.us` here, with DNS service and automatic DNS updates enabled.

**I've successfully joined the two VMs to the domain. But the dynamic DNS updates are only putting AAAA records into the DNS. No A records are ever inserted.**

[image: DNS RRs]

My DNS zone settings for dyanmic updates and BIND update policy appear to be correct as well.

[image: DNS zone settings]

Both client VMs actually *have* IPv4 addresses; `puppet` has a static IPv4 address and `wordpress` gets its IPv4 address from DHCP. This doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
# ip a s dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:3c:d5:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.50.227/24 brd 172.25.50.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 2001:db8:16:bf:5054:ff:fe3c:d5f5/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 86180sec preferred_lft 14180sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe3c:d5f5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The trouble actually seems to be with sssd, which I learned is actually responsible for pushing the dynamic DNS updates. I cranked up debugging with `debug_level = 9` and found this in the logs. It seems to indicate that sssd isn't even bothering with attempting to send an A record, though it doesn't really give me any indication why.

```
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [ipa_dyndns_update_send] (0x4000): Performing update
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [ok_for_dns] (0x0200): Multicast IPv4 address 172.25.50.227
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [ok_for_dns] (0x0200): Link local IPv6 address fe80::5054:ff:fe3c:d5f5
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [ipa_dyndns_gss_tsig_update_step] (0x1000): Checking if the update is needed
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_get_family_order] (0x1000): Lookup order: ipv6_first
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_is_address] (0x4000): [wordpress.example.us] does not look like an IP address
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_step] (0x2000): Querying DNS
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_dns_query] (0x0100): Trying to resolve AAAA record of 'wordpress.example.us' in DNS
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [schedule_request_timeout] (0x2000): Scheduling a timeout of 5 seconds
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [schedule_timeout_watcher] (0x2000): Scheduling DNS timeout watcher
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [unschedule_timeout_watcher] (0x4000): Unscheduling DNS timeout watcher
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [request_watch_destructor] (0x0400): Deleting request watch
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_step] (0x2000): Querying DNS
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_dns_query] (0x0100): Trying to resolve A record of 'wordpress.example.us' in DNS
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [schedule_request_timeout] (0x2000): Scheduling a timeout of 5 seconds
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [schedule_timeout_watcher] (0x2000): Scheduling DNS timeout watcher
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [unschedule_timeout_watcher] (0x4000): Unscheduling DNS timeout watcher
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [request_watch_destructor] (0x0400): Deleting request watch
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_next] (0x0200): No more address families to retry
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_next] (0x0100): No more hosts databases to retry
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_is_address] (0x4000): [wordpress.example.us] does not look like an IP address
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_step] (0x2000): Querying DNS
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_dns_query] (0x0100): Trying to resolve A record of 'wordpress.example.us' in DNS
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [schedule_request_timeout] (0x2000): Scheduling a timeout of 5 seconds
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [schedule_timeout_watcher] (0x2000): Scheduling DNS timeout watcher
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [unschedule_timeout_watcher] (0x4000): Unscheduling DNS timeout watcher
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [request_watch_destructor] (0x0400): Deleting request watch
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_next] (0x0200): No more address families to retry
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [resolv_gethostbyname_next] (0x0100): No more hosts databases to retry
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [ipa_dyndns_gss_tsig_update_check] (0x1000): Address on localhost only: 2001:db8:16:bf:5054:ff:fe3c:d5f5
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [ipa_dyndns_gss_tsig_update_check] (0x0400): Detected IP addresses change, will perform an update
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [create_nsupdate_message] (0x0200): Creating update message for realm [EXAMPLE.US] and zone [example.us].
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [create_nsupdate_message] (0x0400):  -- Begin nsupdate message --
realm EXAMPLE.US
zone example.us.
update delete wordpress.example.us. in A
send
update delete wordpress.example.us. in AAAA
send
update add wordpress.example.us. 86400 in AAAA 2001:db8:16:bf:5054:ff:fe3c:d5f5
send
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [create_nsupdate_message] (0x0400):  -- End nsupdate message --
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [child_handler_setup] (0x2000): Setting up signal handler up for pid [2144]
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [child_handler_setup] (0x2000): Signal handler set up for pid [2144]
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [write_pipe_handler] (0x0400): All data has been sent!
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [ipa_dyndns_stdin_done] (0x4000): Sending nsupdate data complete
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [child_sig_handler] (0x1000): Waiting for child [2144].
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [child_sig_handler] (0x0100): child [2144] finished successfully.
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [sss_child_handler] (0x2000): waitpid failed [10]: No child processes
(Mon Jul 22 21:50:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [ipa_dyndns_update_done] (0x0020): DNS update finished
```

My `sssd.conf` is:

```
[domain/example.us]

cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
ipa_domain = example.us
id_provider = ipa
auth_provider = ipa
access_provider = ipa
ipa_hostname = wordpress.example.us
chpass_provider = ipa
ipa_dyndns_update = True
ipa_server = _srv_, ipadc1.example.us
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ipa/ca.crt
[sssd]
services = nss, pam, ssh
config_file_version = 2

domains = example.us
[nss]

[pam]

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]

[pac]
```

The result of `ipa dnszone-show example.us --all` is:

```
  dn: idnsname=example.us,cn=dns,dc=example,dc=us
  Zone name: example.us
  Authoritative nameserver: ipadc1.example.us.
  Administrator e-mail address: hostmaster.example.us.
  SOA serial: 1374982142
  SOA refresh: 3600
  SOA retry: 900
  SOA expire: 1209600
  SOA minimum: 3600
  BIND update policy: grant EXAMPLE.US krb5-self * A; grant EXAMPLE.US krb5-self
                      * AAAA; grant EXAMPLE.US krb5-self * SSHFP;
  Active zone: TRUE
  Dynamic update: TRUE
  Allow query: any;
  Allow transfer: none;
  mxrecord: 0 mail.example.us
  nsrecord: ipadc1.example.us.
  objectclass: top, idnsrecord, idnszone
  txtrecord: v=spf1 a mx -all
```

While this is really a minor issue for me, since I *could* go live without IPv4 DNS updates (it's nice to be 100% dual stack) it's still annoying to not know what's going on here. Perhaps there are logs that I missed that would shed light on the situation?

(Oh, and yes I turned it off and on again.)

Comment: wow, everything looks exactly like I have. Probably some bug, i have lower version, you need to ask Jacob on #freeipa @freenode. Also can you try from that machine manually send the update you should have keytab for that. `nsupdate >update add wordpress.example.us 86400 A 172.25.50.227` ?

Comment: @DanilaLadner Yes, if I manually run `nsupdate` then I can update the records. The problem seems to be that `sssd` is not telling `nsupdate` to update the A record.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you have added

```
ipa_dyndns_iface = eth0
```

in that pastebin i see sssd recognize your ip as multicast:

`"(Tue Jul  9 10:00:01 2013) [sssd[be[example.us]]] [ok_for_dns] (0x0200): Multicast IPv4 address 172.25.50.227"`

in the piece of code Jacob wrote where he would test for looback addresses, multicast addresses e.t.c. not to report to dns you will find your error:

```
if (IN_MULTICAST(ntohl(addr->s_addr))) {
        DEBUG(SSSDBG_FUNC_DATA, ("Multicast IPv4 address %s\n", straddr));
        return false;
    } else if (inet_netof(*addr) == IN_LOOPBACKNET) {
        DEBUG(SSSDBG_FUNC_DATA, ("Loopback IPv4 address %s\n", straddr));
        return false;
    } else if ((addr->s_addr & 0xffff0000) == 0xa9fe0000) {
        /* 169.254.0.0/16 */
        DEBUG(SSSDBG_FUNC_DATA, ("Link-local IPv4 address %s\n", straddr));
        return false;
    } else if (addr->s_addr == htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST)) {
        DEBUG(SSSDBG_FUNC_DATA, ("Broadcast IPv4 address %s\n", straddr));
        return false;
    }
} else {
    DEBUG(SSSDBG_CRIT_FAILURE, ("Unknown address family\n"));
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Now the question is why is it recognized as "multicast addr" i have no idea. As IN_MULTICAST in `in.h` you can see:

```
   "IN_MULTICAST(a)" - tests whether a is a multicast address. and it is in "inet.h/in.h":
   #define  IN_CLASSD(i)        (((long)(i) & 0xf0000000) == 0xe0000000)
   #define  IN_MULTICAST(i)     IN_CLASSD(i)
```

So how that IP Address evaluated to multicast, i would try to strace it and look.  Also you could ask Jacob Hrozek, he wrote that piece of sssd code. He usually always available at #sssd on freenode, would be great if you'd share what you end up with on this.
Hope it helps a little.

### EDIT

Yeah, there is a bug in your version 1.9.2.  You have:

```
  if (IN_MULTICAST(addr->s_addr))) {
```

It should be:

```
  if (IN_MULTICAST(ntohl(addr->s_addr))) {
```

Comment: It's a bog standard RFC 1918 address, and certainly not IPv4 multicast. So I think you're right that this is some sort of bug. Which source file was this in?

Comment: yeah, it is very weird.

Comment: dyndns.c  https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/sssd.git/tree/src/providers/ipa/ipa_dyndns.c?id=27cf6c28bc02e7a54487d44c212a98b165a70c34

Comment: what version of your sssd rpm?

Comment: sssd-1.9.2-82.7.el6_4.x86_64

Comment: Wish I could upvote this a lot more than once.  What a comprehensive and precise answer; applause!

Comment: Looking at the source for 1.9.2 in git, I can see that the call to `ntohl` is missing. This confirms that [it's a bug](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/ticket/1804), which it appears was fixed in commit [27cf6c2](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/changeset/27cf6c28bc02e7a54487d44c212a98b165a70c34/). Red Hat, unfortunately, isn't planning to fix this [until EL7](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=909430)...

Comment: yeah, that sucks, oh well. but other than that FreeIPA in my opinion is worth playing with, and I think sssd went much farther than nscd ( a buggy piece of slow caching crap).

Comment: Yep, I'm excited to use it. Good thing I don't need IPv4 :)

Comment: This is supposedly [fixed in RHEL 6](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2014-1375.html) now.

Answer (score 1):

From the `sssd-ipa(5)` manpage:

```
   ipa_dyndns_iface (string)
       Optional. Applicable only when ipa_dyndns_update is true. Choose the interface whose IP address should be used for dynamic DNS updates.

       Default: Use the IP address of the IPA LDAP connection
```

You must set `ipa_dyndns_iface` in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` to match the interface of the IPA server, as the default is to only use the address of the socket towards the IPA server:

```
ipa_dyndns_iface = eth0
```

That should enable dynamic updates for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Nice try, but didn't seem to help. The results of adding this are [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/m7QUAJm9).

Answer (score 0):

Also try setting the *lookup_family_order* to non-default value such as *ipv6_first* as a test-case and inform us if it tries ipv4 at all.

Comment: This also [had no effect](http://pastebin.com/N7tpzPBE).